# Google people.people.connections.list pagination seems to be broken

Tags: google-api, google-people-api

When I submit a request using the nextPage token to paginate through lists larger than 500, i get the following error:

```
500 HTTP/2.0 500
- Show headers -

{
 "error": {
  "code": 500,
  "message": "Internal error encountered.",
  "status": "INTERNAL"
 }
}
```

Fiddling with the token gives appropriate detailed error on a bad token.

Comment: encountered the same error in google api explorer.

Answer (score 2):

thanks for reporting the issue. We've identified a bug in one of the backend services when sync is requested and pagination is done on the first sync request without passing in the sync token. We have submitted a fix, which should be rolled out shortly.

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Comment: This should be fixed now!